# how to get the values of particular key in a collection

Tags: javascript

if i have this collection:

```
var objArray = [
        { id: 0, name: 'Object 0', otherProp: '321' },
        { id: 1, name: 'O1', otherProp: '648' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Another Object', otherProp: '850' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Almost There', otherProp: '046' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Last Obj', otherProp: '984' }
    ];
```

how to get the array of id's values, example result:
{0,1,2,3,4}

any idea?

i have been googleing it but i can not get the answer, mostly done by filtering.

Comment: Try `objArray.map(o => o.id)`. Also your result format is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try using reduce.

```js
var objArray = [
        { id: 0, name: 'Object 0', otherProp: '321' },
        { id: 1, name: 'O1', otherProp: '648' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Another Object', otherProp: '850' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Almost There', otherProp: '046' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Last Obj', otherProp: '984' }
    ];
    
var res = objArray.reduce(function(out, inp) {
              out.push(inp['id']);
              return out;
          }, []);
    
    console.log(res)
```